# ionic build --verbose android error ts2740

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

Type '{ children: Element[]; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<any, "slot" | "style" | "title" | "children" | "defaultChecked" | "defaultValue" | "suppressContentEditableWarning" | "suppressHydrationWarning" | "accessKey" | "className" | ... 247 more ... | "animation">': slot, style, title, defaultChecked, and 253 more.  TS2740[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smLce.png)

Comment: There is no question here. Please provide more context and the relevant code.